# Multipeer Connectivity iOS7 multiple devices connected to same session

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

On each device in the view did load I initiated an MCSession. Then the user can tap on any device he/she wants and send a request to that peer using:

```
[browser invitePeer:peerID
       toSession:session
     withContext:context
         timeout:timeout];
```

I have two concerns:

1) I notice that If two devices are already connected, and a third device asks to connect to one of these two devices, it will automatically be connected with both the requested one and the other one already in the session. The three devices will be all connected. This is fine, but the problem is that:

2) When one of the three devices disconnects from the session using:

```
[session disconnect];
```

it seems that data can't be sent anymore to the other, still connected device (maybe the device is still trying to send some data to the disconnected device, in-fact lost peer is not called immediately...).

Comment: Do you receive session:peer:didChangeState: on your MCSessionDelegate for only the peer that sent the `[session disconnect]`?

Comment: @JuJoDi I'll check now

Comment: Doesn't seem it is NSLogging both devices, but only one. I am having trouble reproducing the problem. Now I have a new problem: once I have disconnected one device, I cannot connect it back...

Comment: How can a third device ask to be connected? A device has to send a message to the third device inviting it to the session.

Comment: No, the third device can invite any of the two connected devices for a session, and all three will then be connected.